# How can I set PermissionsEdit and PermissionsRead on a custom field using SOAP?

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api, tooling-api

How can I set PermissionsEdit and PermissionsRead on a custom field using SOAP?  What is the URL endpoint and XML structure?

I found this doc, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm, that looks close but there is no endpoint or specific XML to set these permissions for all or one profile sets.

Comment: Are you looking only for SOAP? or does even REST works fine for you? The REST should be easier to implement than using SOAP

Comment: Apparently you can't do this with the REST API...